# How encode file content without question diamonds onActivityResult?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I get file content bytes by this way:

```
val content = data.data?.let { uri -> contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { it!!.readBytes()} }
```

and then I tried to get file content without black diamonds with question mark:

```
val encodedFileString = String(content!!, Charset.forName("UTF8"))
```

but I didn't succeed in it :( right now I can get only such string:

```
P=�ʍ�̗�e�1�WO���ݨ��zc��s�~$$�jꮘ2E�'���ΰ] �A�.�Q�/�.�S���D@UU��I-m&��֖�ʘb����i��ZR�2��0�U�Hd�֖�R��Z�D�c�al�(k��/0��0��v0�)Ks%5FV�**VL�,k~����Z���@��8��}��AREm�:H�W-_��TL/�kť�p�Y+`+�&M0�VqW��;x�du>#�ꙩ�Om?H�E�NΜ誥k���@�1�z6�냍����jĺ?�!�Q��W�I�!Ws�@W]���C�J��ft��e
```

Maybe someone knows how to get file content without these marks and represent file in another place without problems?

Comment: What kind of file? Only a plain text file you can threat as a string.

Comment: @blackapps, it can be image, docx or txt files, it can be every file, maybe I convert file to string in a wrong way :(

Comment: Repeat: you can only handle a txt file as a string. I wonder what you wanna do with the file in this way. I see no purpose.

Comment: I get file content as text, and then I will need to encode it, or about what you asked?

Comment: No you can directly encode from `val content`. And then you did not tell us what kind of encoding that would be.

Comment: it has to be as ascii I think, smth like that `c³UvµØ\u00120Ý<%\u0000\u0001ÃÌ¸½í÷\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000e\u001eeT}«ªû¬,$î\u000b\u001bÏßqá=oñ{¯µ±:¬%¶×Ém\u0007_Q õZ®¯»î÷^È²âï³¹Nìµvy»û?¢z\u001fgl\u0000\u0000\u0000*\u0010ú\u001b4ªL´ÆJÇÊßY®ôÏÅúxÖµx·ÛkþÝYñíV-õ¶_?N\u0003®`

Comment: That does not look very much like ascii. But... should you start telling why you wanna encode in which encoding? Whats the purpose?

Comment: maybe it is utf-8 encoding, I would like to send this string to certain server, and he receives such symbols of file content

Comment: It makes no sense to encode an image as utf-8. Further: if you wanna send a file then send the file.

Comment: I have to send such type of string, for example at JS server use such function - `fr.readAsBinaryString(...);`

Comment: If you put an image in a string and then try to print the string then it is quite normal that you see those characters. Try a txt file and you should not see them.

Comment: if I use txt file all content is represented in normal way, but when I try to send image content server returns me an error

Comment: You did nit tell that before. And you will not tell us which error exactly?

Comment: `open(fp, 'wb').write(form['body'].encode('latin-1'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)` - this one

Comment: Please put complete server receiving code in your post. And put also the error in your post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627839/how-to-create-normal-json-with-normal-utf-8-string-kotlin-android - here are these errors, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: But you should not on server side apply yet an encoding. Latin-1 is for text only. The error tells you such.